# como iterar con panda 'subdataframes' en cada iteracion y modificando el dataframe original

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A ver si alguien sabe como hacer esto.
Tengo un dataframe con varias columnas.
Uno de los campos es ID. Tengo que hacer selecciones de filas por el ID.
Para cada grupo de filas del mismo ID, tengo que  hacer unas operaciones que modifiquen el dataframe original.

Este es codigo que intento pero no me modifica el dataframe original. El bucle for interno lo he probado solo un un ID y si me hace lo que quiero, pero al meter el bucle exterior para automaticamente lo haga con todos los grupos de ID no va.

```
#recorremos el dataframe para detectar los viajes y añadir informacion
#lista es un array con los ID
#misDatos es el dataframe con los datos originales

for m in range (len(lista)):

    individual = misDatos['hwId'] == lista[m]#selecciono cada id
    subdatos = misDatos[individual]#hago un 'subdataframe' solo con los registros del id

    roll_iter = zip(subdatos.index, subdatos.index[1:])  #creo un iterador con 2 indices

    for i,j in roll_iter:  
            #si la posicion varia pongo 'viaje' a true en la segunda fila
        if (subdatos.at[i,'lat']!= subdatos.at[j,'lat'])or(subdatos.at[i,'lon']!= subdatos.at[j,'lon']):  

            subdatos.at[j,'viaje'] = True 

            #calculo el tiempo que ha durado un viaje
            subdatos.at[j,'tiempoviaje'] = subdatos.at[j,'ts']-subdatos.at[i,'ts']

            #calculo el consumo de bateria del viaje
            subdatos.at[j,'consumo'] = abs(subdatos.at[i,'carga']-subdatos.at[j,'carga'])


            try:
                next(roll_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ningún punto de código haces asignaciones a misDatos, haces asignaciones al dataframe subdatos, por eso nunca modificas el original.

Si no he entendido mal, deberías de sustituir poner misDatos de la siguiente forma:

```
#recorremos el dataframe para detectar los viajes y añadir informacion
#lista es un array con los ID
#misDatos es el dataframe con los datos originales

for m in range (len(lista)):

    individual = misDatos['hwId'] == lista[m]#selecciono cada id
    subdatos = misDatos[individual]#hago un 'subdataframe' solo con los registros del id

    roll_iter = zip(subdatos.index, subdatos.index[1:])  #creo un iterador con 2 indices

    for i,j in roll_iter:  
            #si la posicion varia pongo 'viaje' a true en la segunda fila
        if (subdatos.at[i,'lat']!= subdatos.at[j,'lat'])or(subdatos.at[i,'lon']!= subdatos.at[j,'lon']):  

            misDatos.at[j,'viaje'] = True 

            #calculo el tiempo que ha durado un viaje
            misDatos.at[j,'tiempoviaje'] = subdatos.at[j,'ts']-subdatos.at[i,'ts']

            #calculo el consumo de bateria del viaje
            misDatos.at[j,'consumo'] = abs(subdatos.at[i,'carga']-subdatos.at[j,'carga'])


            try:
                next(roll_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                break
```

Es decir, haces los cálculos en subdatos y le asignas el valor a misDatos, para que se te modifique.